# Support vector regression versus kernel ridge regression

Tags: machine-learning, svm, ridge-regression, kernel-trick

I have a question concerning the difference between support vector regression and kernel regression. I will try to write down all the math so no misunderstandings arise (hopefully).

Let's begin with the minimization problem associated with SVR. Assume we observe responses $y_1,\dots,y_n$ together with predictors $x_1,\dots,x_n$ where $x_i=(x_{i1},\dots,x_{ip})$. Denote by $w_i$ the weight of the kernel function $K_i(\cdot)$ associated with predictor $x_i$, and by $C$ the weight of the loss function. Then the SVR problem expressed as a minimization problem is
$$\begin{align} \text{min} & \sum_i^n w_i^2 + C\sum_i^n (\xi_i^- + \xi_i^+) 
\\ s.t. \ \ & \xi_i^- \geq y_i- b -\sum_j^n w_jK_j(x_{i})-\epsilon, \ &i=1,\dots,n \\ 
& \xi_i^+ \geq b + \sum_j^n w_jK_j(x_{i})- y_i -\epsilon \ &i=1,\dots,n \\ &w_i, \xi_i^+, \xi_i^- \geq 0 \ & i=1,\dots,n\end{align} $$

Now $K_i(x)$ can be some kernel function, centered at $x_i$, e.g., the Gaussian kernel

$$ K_i(x) = \text{e}^{-\gamma||x_i-x||^2} $$

with $\gamma$ as a hyperparameter to be defined.

For the optimality it holds that $$
\xi_i^+ + \xi_i^- = \begin{cases} b + \sum_j^n w_jK_j(x_{i})- y_i &\text{ if } b + \sum_j^n w_jK_j(x_{i})- y_i \geq 0 \\ y_i- b -\sum_j^n w_jK_j(x_{i}) & \text{else,} \end{cases}$$
which can be rewritten as 
$$
\xi_i^+ + \xi_i^- = \left| b + \sum_j^n w_jK_j(x_{i})- y_i \right|. $$

If we further assume that $\epsilon\approx 0$, we can write the minimization problem more compactly by

$$\text{min}_{w_i,i=1,\dots,n}\sum_i^n w_i^2 + C\sum_i^n \left| y_i-b-\sum_j^n w_jK_j(x_{i}) \right|.$$

For anyone doing ridge regression, this already looks familiar.

Let us now replace the absolute error with the squared error and premultiply by $\lambda = \frac{1}{C}$ and we arrive at the following minimization problem

$$\text{min}_{w_i,i=1,\dots,n}\lambda \sum_i^n w_i^2 + \sum_i^n \left( y_i-b-\sum_j^n w_jK_j(x_{i})-b_0 \right)^2,$$
which is the equivalent kernel ridge regression problem.

So the difference between support vector regression (with zero slack/epsilon) and kernel ridge regression boils down to having two different type of loss function.

That's really all that is behind it? Considering the tremendous difference in computational performance between performing least squares versus solving a linear program, I wonder why I should use SVR at all. Does the absolute error perform so much better than the squared error on real data to justify the computational effort?

Answer (score 4):

As expected: it depends on what you want. In terms of generalization performance, typically the performance differences are minor.

That said, minimizing the $l_1$-norm has the extremely attractive feature of yielding sparse solutions (the support vectors are a subset of the training set). When doing ridge regression, just like in least-squares SVM, all training instances become support vectors and you end up with a model the size of your training set. A large model requires a lot of memory (obviously) and is slower in prediction.

Comment: I can see your point for classication tasks, where I want to separate two sets of data points, but with regression on noisy data, there is no such thing as a support vector, but rather a function approximation which provides me with the best fit.

Comment: So whether I choose L1 or L2 is merely a mean how I penalize the errors. To me, L1 seems to be the most natural choice in one dimension, but solving the QP comes at a cost.I also do not quite understand the argument regarding sparsity, since I penalize the parameter vector $w$ quadratically. If I could replace one Kernel with another, I would still try to use both to get a lower sum of squares. I conjecture that combining the least squares SVR formulation, as you call it, with LASSO may be the better choice if what I want is less Kernels to reduce memory and accelerate prediction.